# why every time is visit my product details page it is auto scrolling to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Whenever I'm clicking on a card to go to the product details page it is automatically going to the bottom of the next page without even scrolling it here is the sample of my code

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Rating } from "@material-ui/lab";

const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  const options = {
    value: product.ratings,
    readOnly: true,
    precision: 0.5,
  };
  return (
    <Link className="productCard" to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
      <img src={product.images[0].url} alt={product.name} />
      <p>{product.name}</p>
      <div>
        <Rating {...options} />
        <span className="productCardSpan">
          {""}({product.numOfReviews} Reviews)
        </span>
      </div>
      <span>{`₹${product.price}/-`}</span>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

product details page is starting from here

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  clearErrors,
  getProductDetails,
  newReview,
} from "../../actions/productAction";
import ReviewCard from "./ReviewCard.js";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import { addItemsToCart } from "../../actions/cartAction";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  Button,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Rating } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { NEW_REVIEW_RESET } from "../../constants/productConstants";

const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();

  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );

  const { success, error: reviewError } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.newReview
  );

  const options = {
    size: "large",
    value: product.ratings,
    readOnly: true,
    precision: 0.5,
  };

  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");

  const increaseQuantity = () => {
    if (product.Stock <= quantity) return;

    const qty = quantity + 1;
    setQuantity(qty);
  };

  const decreaseQuantity = () => {
    if (1 >= quantity) return;

    const qty = quantity - 1;
    setQuantity(qty);
  };

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    dispatch(addItemsToCart(match.params.id, quantity));
    alert.success("Item Added To Cart");
  };

  const submitReviewToggle = () => {
    open ? setOpen(false) : setOpen(true);
  };

  const reviewSubmitHandler = () => {
    const myForm = new FormData();

    myForm.set("rating", rating);
    myForm.set("comment", comment);
    myForm.set("productId", match.params.id);

    dispatch(newReview(myForm));

    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }

    if (reviewError) {
      alert.error(reviewError);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }

    if (success) {
      alert.success("Review Submitted Successfully");
      dispatch({ type: NEW_REVIEW_RESET });
    }
    dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
  }, [dispatch, match.params.id, error, alert, reviewError, success]);
  console.log(product.images);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <MetaData title={`${product.name} -- ECOMMERCE`} />
          <div className="ProductDetails">
            <div>
             
              {product.images &&
                product.images.map((item, i) => (
                  <img
                    className="CarouselImage"
                    key={i}
                    src={item.url}
                    alt="product"
                  />
                ))}
            </div>

            <div>
              <div className="detailsBlock-1">
                <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                <p>Product # {product._id}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="detailsBlock-2">
                <Rating {...options} />
                <span className="detailsBlock-2-span">
                  {" "}
                  ({product.numOfReviews} Reviews)
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="detailsBlock-3">
                <h1>{`₹${product.price}`}</h1>
                <div className="detailsBlock-3-1">
                  <div className="detailsBlock-3-1-1">
                    <button onClick={decreaseQuantity}>-</button>
                    <input readOnly type="number" value={quantity} />
                    <button onClick={increaseQuantity}>+</button>
                  </div>
                  <button
                    disabled={product.Stock < 1 ? true : false}
                    onClick={addToCartHandler}
                  >
                    Add to Cart
                  </button>
                </div>

                <p>
                  Status:
                  <b className={product.Stock < 1 ? "redColor" : "greenColor"}>
                    {product.Stock < 1 ? "OutOfStock" : "InStock"}
                  </b>
                </p>
              </div>

              <div className="detailsBlock-4">
                Description : <p>{product.description}</p>
              </div>

              <button onClick={submitReviewToggle} className="submitReview">
                Submit Review
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <h3 className="reviewsHeading">REVIEWS</h3>

          <Dialog
            aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
            open={open}
            onClose={submitReviewToggle}
          >
            <DialogTitle>Submit Review</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent className="submitDialog">
              <Rating
                onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
                value={rating}
                size="large"
              />

              <textarea
                className="submitDialogTextArea"
                cols="30"
                rows="5"
                value={comment}
                onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
              ></textarea>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={submitReviewToggle} color="secondary">
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={reviewSubmitHandler} color="primary">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>

          {product.reviews && product.reviews[0] ? (
            <div className="reviews">
              {product.reviews &&
                product.reviews.map((review) => (
                  <ReviewCard key={review._id} review={review} />
                ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <p className="noReviews">No Reviews Yet</p>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

I tried linking in it but it won't work and someone told me to use useRef but i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using React router dom. In React Router there is the problem that if we redirect to the new route, it won't automatically take you to the top of the page. Such behavior is normal when you navigate between pages.
Since you are using functional components

Try to use the following window scroll to the top when the component mounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}, [])
```

Comment: @shoaibullakhan in which component have added the `useEffect`?

Comment: yes it is working fine and thank for your input....i pasted in wrong element that's why it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Browser scroll your page.

If you don't want to let browser auto scroll your page,
use `History.scrollRestoration` method

Prevent automatic page location restoration

```
if (history.scrollRestoration) {
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

Read more at [MDN History.scrollRestoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration)